# Rotate 'left' from the perspective of the space ship

Tags: c#, rotation, quaternion

I'm stuck on the following math problem for my game project. I have a space ship which position and orientation is saved in the following class:

*(The examples are in C# using types from the System.Numerics namespace)*

```csharp
class Transform
{
  Quaternion Rotation;
  Vector3 Position;
}
```

If I want to move the space ship forward, as seen from the reference frame (perspective) of the space ship I can do the following

```csharp
transform.Position += Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0, 0, -1), Rotation);
```

If I want to turn my space ship left (yaw 90 degrees counter clockwise). I could do:

```csharp
var relativeUp = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), Rotation);
var rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(relativeUp, PI / 2);
transform.Rotation = rotation * transform.Rotation;
```

But I want to write this method:

```
void RotateInReferenceFrame(Quaternion q);
```

Where the input quaternion `q` is constructed as `Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll((PI/2, 0, 0)` (so unaware of the current orientation of the space ship) but the resulting rotation is done in the reference frame of the space ship (so the result is the same as the 2 step example above).

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you just want the composition of two quaternions? (ie. their product)

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I made an error in my unit test that made me think that the composition rotates in world space, not local space. I'll answer with a complete example.

Comment: It can rotate in either space, it just depends on the order of the terms: `world * current` or `current * local`.

Comment: Ahh, I've updated my answer. But what does Concatenating two quaternions do in that case? As qCurrent + qOffset seems to give the same answer as qOffset*qCurrent?

Comment: I'm honestly baffled by that method. I went searching earlier to try to determine the difference since the documentation doesn't specify, and came up empty-handed. 

Answer (score 1):

DMGregory is absolutely right, but I had an error in my unit tests that put me on the wrong path. The following code is correct.

```csharp
using System.Numerics;

readonly struct Transform
{
    readonly Vector3 Position;
    readonly Quaternion Rotation;
    
    Quaternion Rotate(Quaternion offset)
    {
        return  Quaternion.Multiply(offset, this.GetRotation());
    }

    Quaternion RotateInLocalReferenceFrame(Quaternion offset)
    {
        return Quaternion.Multiply(this.GetRotation(), offset);
    }

    Vector3 GetForward()
    {        
        return Vector3.Transform(-Vector3.UnitZ, this.Rotation);
    }
}
```

The behavior makes sense when seen from a simple smoke test

```csharp
using static Xunit.Assert;

class TransformTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void SmokeTest()
    {
        Transform t = default;
        
        // Rolling the ship counter clockwise makes the nose point up
        t = t.RotateInLocalReferenceFrame(Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(0, MathF.PI / 2, 0));
        // Helper method that checks if all the elements of a vector are within 0.001 of the expected value
        AlmostEqual(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), t.GetForward());

        // Yawing the ship in a local reference frame makes the nose point left. If this was done from
        // a global reference frame this would not have changed where the nose points.
        t = t.RotateLocalInReferenceFrame(Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathF.PI / 2, 0, 0));
        AlmostEqual(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), t.GetForward());

        // Rolling the ship in a gobal reference makes the nose point down. If this was done from 
        // a local reference frame this would not have changed where the nose points
        t = t.Rotate(Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(0, 0, MathF.PI / 2));
        AlmostEqual(new Vector3(0, -1, 0), t.GetForward());
    }
}
```